# Objective-C Class Swapping at runtime

Tags: ios, objective-c

At the moment we have a class structure like...

```
GenericFruitViewController
    - AppleViewController
    - PearViewController
    - StrawberryViewController
```

Where the specific view controllers are subclasses and only change a small amount of implementation.

What I'd like to do is be able to swap out the `GenericViewController` at runtime. I want to change the way the generic view controller works and change some of the methods (this won't affect the subclassed overridden methods).

But I'd like to be able to switch this on/off (A/B testing).

At the moment we have a factory method that does something like...

```
- (GenericFruitViewController *)fruitControllerWithType:(FruitType)type
{
    if (type == Apple) {
        return [AppleViewController new];
    }

    return [GenericFruitViewController new];
}
```

What I'd like to do (ideally) is something like...

```
- (GenericFruitViewController *)fruitControllerWithType:(FruitType)type
{
    // this is the new bit!
    if (switchOnTheTesting) {
        // swap GenericFruitViewController for my NewFruitViewController
    }
    // new bit ends

    // existing code not changed
    if (type == Apple) {
        // this now returns a subclass of NewFruitVC if switched
        return [AppleViewController new];
    }

    // this now returns NewFruitVC if switched
    return [GenericFruitViewController new];
}
```

And by doing this it will then use my new VC whenever it refers to the `GenericFruitVC`.

Is that even possible?

Comment: save the class of the controller and use it instead of referring to the controller class directly.

Comment: @Sulthan but I don't think that would work with being able to keep the subclass hierarchy against the new class?

Comment: Oh, I see what you want. you can replace an implementation of a method but you cannot replace the superclass of a class. It looks more like an architecture problem.

Comment: @Sulthan yeah that's right. A bit like method swizzling (I think) but for a class. My other option is to create the new superclass and all the subclasses. (Or maybe some other approach entirely) lol! Thanks :-)

Comment: Maybe use delegation? Extract the mutable methods from `GenericFruitViewController` into a separate class and delegate the functionality there? Changing implementation is then very simple without method/class swizzling.

Comment: @Sulthan yeah I was thinking about decoupling everything anyway. Might be a better solution altogether. :D